# Styling the rows and column width in asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How do I style my gridview ?

i. I need to remove the borders in the table rows.How do I do that ?

ii. How do I change the row width and insert a scrollbar?

iii. How do I filter a grid view column for a value ?

Comment: you can specify css styles for all the properties like row,header,footer,alternative row etc.Remember one thing ASP.NET gridview will render common html table .

Comment: Google `asp.net skins`: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11886/Themes-and-Skins-in-ASP-NET

Comment: Row width -> anyone? .The links mention about the column width only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `CssClass` of gridview and create a css class and set it accordingly.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvEmployee" runat="server" CssClass="Grid" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
                  PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" >
```

and create a css class as follows

You can visit this link http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/gridview-custom-css-style-example-in-Asp-Net-1088.aspx

```
.Grid 
 { 
    border:none;

 }
 .Grid tr
 { 
    border:none;
    width:100px !important;
 }
 /*for first td*/
 .Grid td
 { 
    border:none;
    width:100px !important;
 }
 /*for second td*/
 .Grid td+td
 { 
    border:none;
    width:150px !important;
 }
```

etc.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: don't use the border-collapse.  then what is the issue now?

Comment: I want to remove the borders of the table and the rows and resize the columns according to text length.

Comment: How do i change the row width ?

Comment: your can create classes for `tr` and `td` and use that I am going to update my answer.

Comment: As I've mentioned in my question,I am using a gridView